# How get the cost price?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-online

I have the following spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet]

For column B, the formula is simple: B1 + (B1 * A2)

The question is: how to get the numbers in column C?

I manually typed all values on column C but the idea is if I type 24200 on C1, it calculates all the other values.

24200 - 10% = 21780

21780 is 220 less than the initial price of 22000.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Your Title mentions "cost price" but this isn't isn't mentioned in the body of the question. What's the relationship between Column B and Column C?

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

Cell C1:`=B11`

Cell C2:`=$C$1-($C$1/(1+.1)*A2)`

Comment: it works, but only up to 10%. if I want to extend to 20%, not anymore.

Comment: You specifically cited 1-10%. If you want to extend to 20% then you must reflect this in the formula. The equivalent formulas would be C1:`=B21` (or "26400") and C2:`=$C$1-($C$1/1.2*A2)`

Answer (score 1):

After deleting `B2:B11` and `C2:C11`, put this formula in `B2`:

```
=index($B$1+$B$1*A2:A11)
```

and this other in `C2`:

```
=index($C$1-$C$1/1.1*A2:A11)
```

columns `B` and `C` will fill themselves